# In-memory cache in ASP.NET Core emptied immediately

Tags: caching, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to implement temporary ip blocking for my ASP.NET Core application and everything I have read on how to do this uses caching.

I have followed this article to learn about in-memory caching in asp.net core: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/memory

The code is running okay, but the cache is emptied immediately after an action is completed.

If a put a break-point on this line:

```
_cache.Set(CacheKeys.Entry, cacheEntry, cacheEntryOptions);
```

I can see that _cache indeed has the proper value. However, that value is gone the next time I reload the page. Regardless of how long I set the expiration time to or even if I set

```
CacheItemPriority.NeverRemove
```

in the cacheEntryOptions.

I have also tried registering a callback for the eviction of the item from the cache to see if it was being evicted immediately due to memory pressure. However, the callback is never called.

Is there some server options I need to enable to allow caching?

Comment: Do you use the right scope in DI for the memory cache? This sounds like scoped or transient. For your case, you should use singleton. Otherwise, every time the controller gets created, your data is lost... Or, do you dispose the cache? Are you using a `using` statment around your code?

Comment: @MichaC He dont need to scope DI cuz `AddMemoryCache` have it build in

Comment: I do not know how to scope or whether I should. I do not intentionally dispose the cache, but it does look like it gets destroyed every time the controller is created. I am not using a using statement around the code. My code is exactly the same as that of the article. I have tried installing nugget packages which do temporary IP blocking with the cache, as I am trying to do. They suffer from the same problem as far as I can tell. So I am guessing it is not the code. I tried the package AspNetCoreRateLimit - no luck.

Comment: I'm experiencing this as well w/  MemoryCache in ASP.NET Core 2.  Is it related to IISExpress in my dev environment or something?

Answer (score 0):

I met the similar issue today. And found that the cache only save the reference of the value. So if you save a List in to the cache and Clear the List later. The cached List will also be cleared, but key is still there.
Source code is here:https://source.dot.net/#Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Abstractions/MemoryCacheExtensions.cs,bc5684b7eae179d4

Answer (score 0):

Just as Jun said, values in the cache seem to be a reference. So, if you try to set an object in cache and then you filter it (say a list), the filtered list will be updated in cache.

When reading cache, to avoid that behavior, using `ToList()` is not enough. In my case it's a view model with a list, so I created a new view model and basically mapped from the cached object to that one. This way, I can filter in the `newViewModel` instance that I created without affecting the cache.

Similarly, when using `_cache.TryGetValue`, I want to filter the list before displaying it (I cache 30 values but allow the user to filter a number of 5 for example). `TryGetValue` has an `out` parameter. If you filter that/change it, your cache will be updated AGAIN. So you could do the same workaround, map your cached object to a new instance of that object.